# irregular stackoverflows with hibernate and sqlite in java

Tags: hibernate, sqlite, stack-overflow

I have a java project with Hibernate and SQLite Dialect. In addition I have a model with lots of links among model elements. When I want to store a larger amount of data in the DB, I get an irregular stack overflow. sometimes it works. somtimes it dosnt work.  Why is that?

the exception:

> at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.withResult(Unknown Source)

```
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte.access$000(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByte$Encoder.encodeLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Comment: Can you update your question with 1- the code where the exception occurs and 2- the detail of the exception including ideally the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In java the stack can only hold a certain amount of nested method calls. So if you for instance have a large tree-like structure and the height of the tree is larger then the maximum stack size you will get a stack overflow. Although the most common cause of stack overflow is if you have recursive or circular dependencies.

So my advice to you is to find out if it is possible that you have a circular dependency in your data structure.

If you find that you do not, but that your structure is actually to large, you should consider redesigning or splitting up your data to make it more manageable. As a last resort it is possible to increase your stack size.

Comment: If you post the stack trace and possibly your code, it might be possible to help you find out if you have circular dependencies..

Comment: I also thought it cause by a circular dependency. But why works it sometimes? I dont want to post code. Its a vary large model with many lines of code.

Comment: @user1346330 If possible, try and create a test application that contains the least amount of code to recreate the problem and post that. Many times, this exercise will expose the underlying issue.